# how to save edited webpage on chrome dev tools locally

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am editing a website with Chrome Devloper Tools. I want to access it later when I close the window. In order to do this, there are various tutorials on the web saying I need to add the source folder to workspace and then map the local files. But how do I save the whole edited website ?

I want to save the the complete directory so I can edit different pages again with chrome dev tools and save and go on. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow), if you map a folder Chrome watches that entire folder and *any* changes you make to files (whether in Chrome or outside) are saved to the file system. I have verified this.

So, as long as you map your root folder it will do what you expect and you can use it as a proper IDE.